# Can I add a non-editable field to the class based view UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

```
class EmployeeView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'wfp/employee.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Employee.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get("employee_uuid"))
```

has everything I need except the UUID that is on the employee which is non-editable.

I'd really like to include that in the HTTPResponse so I can use elsewhere a link to another page. (Employee have allocations of things)

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a **`EmployeeModelForm`** class then you can control the process with ease.

```py
# forms.py

from django import forms


class EmployeeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ["your_uuid_field"]
```

and then use the `EmployeeModelForm` class in your view with the help of [**`form_class`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView.form_class) attribute

```py
# views.py

class EmployeeView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeModelForm
    template_name = 'wfp/employee.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Employee.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs.get("employee_uuid"))
```